# SQL function to select event occurring in all 4 quarters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to solve a problem that involves analyzing airfare data over time. Below is a short version of the table:

Quarter city1   city2
1   Albany, NY  Orlando, FL
2   Albany, NY  Orlando, FL
3   Albany, NY  Orlando, FL
4   Albany, NY  Orlando, FL
4   Albany, NY  Los Angeles, CA (Metropolitan Area)
4   Albany, NY  Washington, DC (Metropolitan Area)
2   Albany, NY  Atlanta, GA (Metropolitan Area)

Question: How do I show only unique combinations of city1 and city2, that have occurred in all 4 quarters? In this example, the only row I am looking to return is Albany, NY and Orlando, FL, as the other options did not repeat in all quarters.

I have the following command to show only unique combinations of city1 and city2, but then I get stuck! Help appreciated!

```
    select city1, city2 FROM airfare_data
    UNION
    SELECT city1, city2 from airfare_data
    ORDER BY city1, city2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try  grouping by city and count the distinct quarter from the union between city1 and city2

```
select city 
from (
select quarter, city1 city
from mytable  
union 
select quarter, city2
from mytable )   
group by  city 
having count(distinct quarter)  = 4
```

Comment: Thanks, I played with this a little and came up with the following. I think that it works correctly:
    select city1, city2  
    from airfare_data    
    GROUP BY 1,2  
    HAVING count(DISTINCT quarter)=4  
    union   
    select city1, city2   
    from airfare_data  
    GROUP BY 1,2  
    HAVING count(DISTINCT quarter)=4;    /*

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by city1, city2` and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select city1, city2
from airfare_data
group by city1, city2
having count(distinct Quarter) = 4;
```

If the order of the 2 cities does not matter then you can use the functions [`min()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc) and [`max()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc) like this:

```
select min(city1, city2) city1, max(city1, city2) city2 
from airfare_data
group by min(city1, city2), max(city1, city2)
having count(distinct Quarter) = 4;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJBPEERd7Y7vWDU5eDcz9e/2).
Results:

```
| city1     | city2      |
| --------- | ---------- |
| Albany NY | Orlando FL |
```

Answer (score 0):

Test Data

```
Select 1 as Quarter, 'Albany, NY' as city1, 'Orlando, FL' as city2
into #AirData
 Union
Select 2, 'Albany, NY', 'Orlando, FL' Union
Select 3, 'Albany, NY', 'Orlando, FL' Union
Select 4, 'Albany, NY', 'Orlando, FL' Union
Select 4, 'Albany, NY', 'Los Angeles, CA (Metropolitan Area)' Union
Select 4, 'Albany, NY', 'Washington, DC (Metropolitan Area)' Union
Select 2, 'Albany, NY', 'Atlanta, GA (Metropolitan Area)' Union
Select 3, 'Albany, NY', 'Atlanta, GA (Metropolitan Area)' Union
Select 1, 'Albany, NY', 'Atlanta, GA (Metropolitan Area)' Union
Select 4, 'Albany, NY', 'Atlanta, GA (Metropolitan Area)'
```

and the Query is:

```
select city1, city2
from #AirData 
group by  city1, city2 
having count(distinct quarter)  = 4
```